# how to set query string from the datasource to the <a> tag?

Tags: query-string, repeater

I'm using repeater control from asp.net for binding datasource. I have added  tag element as a template item. I want to set the query string from my table to the href address of the  tag. How to do this in the designing?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two approaches here first is directly in the item template

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <a href="/Folder/Item.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("KeyField") %>">Text</a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Or using hyperlink

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="myLink" runat="server" Text="Text" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

And also you should add some code behind logic on `ItemDataBound` event in the repeater

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
    var myLink = e.Item.FindControl("myLink") as HyperLink;
    myLink.NavigateUrl = String.Format("~/Folder/Item.aspx?ID={0}", (e.Item.DataItem as YourType).KeyField);
}
```

Data item is a single item that represents the DataSource. If your are using `DataTable` it is most likely will be the DataRow. It also can be a custom object or an anonymous type. Here I'm assuming that you have an object named `YourType` with the property `KeyField`